Reformat a Google Sheet based on Data in Column A
I'm trying to work out if there's a way to reformat a sheet, so that the name data relating to a specific order number in Column A, is put into a single row (so that I can perform a subsequent data-merge, keeping all the names from one order in a single document)
Here's the sheet https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19riQ85ggmaAVzA4o0bIDw8q50de9owoL2v3oz6yWTr8/edit?usp=sharing
This is how the data is exported from our online order system

This is what's needed to perform the succesful data-merge

This is something which will need to be done on a daily basis so is it possible to run a script to do this automatically?
Many thanks in advance
Dan

Exact copy of Reformat a Google Sheet based on Data in Column A. See Be Forthright When Cross Posting To Other Sites.

Quoting my answer from Reformat a Google Sheet based on Data in Column A :
=let( 
  filter_, lambda(a, filter(a, len(Sheet1!A3:A), isblank(Sheet1!C3:C))), 
  ids, filter_(Sheet1!A3:A), 
  names, filter_(Sheet1!B3:B), 
  map(unique(ids), lambda(id, 
    hstack(id, torow(filter(names, ids = id))) 
  )) 
)

See
let(),
lambda(),
map(),
hstack(),
unique(),
filter(),
and
torow().

Many thanks, this has worked perfectly

I gather that this is your first question at Stack Exchange. See What should I do when someone answers my question?

Order Numbers vs. Strings
The following formula will work for both numeric and alphanumeric order numbers:
=MAP(UNIQUE(TOCOL(A2:A,1)), LAMBDA(o,
   {o, TOROW(FILTER(B2:B, A2:A=o))}))

Dynamic Column Labels
The formula above can be extended using LET to store the array in arr in order to  create dynamic column labels based on the column count.
=LET(
  arr,MAP(UNIQUE(TOCOL(A2:A,1)), LAMBDA(o,
    {o, TOROW(FILTER(B2:B, A2:A=o))})), 
  {"Order", SORT("Name "& 
    SEQUENCE(1,COLUMNS(arr)-1)); arr})

It's a bit longer but you could also store the range references in variables if it makes the formula easier to read and/or edit:
=LET(
  ord,A2:A, nam,B2:B, 
  arr,MAP(UNIQUE(TOCOL(ord,1)), LAMBDA(o,
   {o, TOROW(FILTER(nam, ord=o))})),
  {"Order", SORT("Name "& 
    SEQUENCE(1,COLUMNS(arr)-1)); arr})

